# Skip some properties of class while iterating with foreach

Tags: c#

I want to skip the ID property while iterating through Student class, but for some cycles the property must be browsable

```
 internal class Student
{
    [DisplayName("N")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Surname")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("ID Number")]
    public string IDNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Mobile Number")]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Class")]
    public byte Grade { get; set; }


    [Browsable(false)]
    public int StatusID { get; set; }
}
```

here is the code that iterates through Student Class properties

```
int num = 1;
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Student).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
  property.SetValue(newStudent, Convert.ChangeType(_textBoxes[num].Text, property.PropertyType));
  num++;
}
```

where _textBoxes[num].text is string

Comment: Where is the code which iterates and which is the lgic to skip the properties?

Comment: Note that "iterate through properties" of a class is not a "standard" behaviour, it requires some custom code (e.g. using reflection): put your skip logic with that (required) code you have to write

Comment: i edited the topic, so i guess it is easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just check the property's name:

```
int num = 1;
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Student).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if (property.Name != nameof(Student.ID))
    {
        property.SetValue(newStudent, Convert.ChangeType(_textBoxes[num].Text, property.PropertyType));
    }

    num++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that might do it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to skip the ID property while iterating through Student class

probably consider creating a ViewModel then with only the required properties like

```
public class StudentViewModel
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string IDNumber { get; set; }

    public string Mobile { get; set; }

    public byte Grade { get; set; }

    public int StatusID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yep that will do it, but dont want to use almost the same new class, I could set those properties one by one like : `newStudent.Firstname = _textBoxes[0].text` but just interested if there is a way to make foreach skip the property i dont want to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Where` provided by `Linq` to filter the properties.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties.Where(x => x.Name != nameof(Student.ID)))
{
    property.SetValue(newStudent, Convert.ChangeType(_textBoxes[num].Text, property.PropertyType));
    num++;
}
```